# Why did `cp -uav` of a git repo show "removed" for some files?

Tags: git, cp, hard-link, coreutils

I used `cp -uav` to update a copy of a git repo, including uncommitted files.

Why did it say it's removing files?  It looks like this:

```
$ cp -uav repos copy
removed 'copy/repos/h/.git/objects/e6/9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391'
removed 'copy/repos/h/.git/objects/3b/b3f834dd037db9298b10d71e0cd7383000fa1c'
removed 'copy/repos/h/.git/objects/49/6d6428b9cf92981dc9495211e6e1120fb6f2ba'
removed 'copy/repos/h/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885'

$ rpm -q --whatprovides `which cp`
coreutils-8.25-17.fc25.x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce the above messages as follows:

```
mkdir test; cd test
mkdir repos; cd repos

mkdir g; cd g
git init
touch a
git add a
git commit -m test
cd ..

git clone g h
cd ..

mkdir copy
cp -ua repos copy
cp -uav repos copy
```

The running the `cp -ua` command under `strace` will show that it is indeed removing (`unlink`) the files it says.

What's happened is that the objects in `repo/h/.git/objects` are hardlinks of the ones in `repo/g/.git/objects`.  (In my original case, I was copying a repo which contained sub-repos, which were originally created as clones of the main repo).

`cp -a` means `cp --preserve`, which is documented as

> --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
>
> preserve  the  specified  attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr,
>                 all

The unlink happens as part of hardlink preservation:

> linkat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "copy/repos/g/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885",
>   AT_FDCWD,
>   "copy/repos/h/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885", 0)
>   = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
>
> unlink("copy/repos/h/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885")
>   = 0
>
> linkat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "copy/repos/g/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885",
>   AT_FDCWD,
>   "copy/repos/h/.git/objects/2b/bf350cea1fb4fd036235d7e6c36eb600e68885", 0)
>   = 0

As to exactly why it generates messages which confused me so?

It seems like `-u` (`--update`) is not quite implemented in this code.  It's mainly a performance optimization to avoid re-copying data unecessarily.  Making hardlinks doesn't require copying any data.

We can see other scenarios in the documentation where `cp` must remove files as well:

> ```
>    -f, --force
>
>          if an existing destination file cannot be opened, remove it and try again (this option is ignored when the -n option is also used)
> ```

In the case of `-f`, I can understand that it might want to show the specific files that it has to "force".

I suppose it might also be useful to show deletion, in case `cp` is interrupted.  Otherwise, users would be unlikely to realize that a file could have been deleted from the destination (as an intermediate step).

The ultimate question is why it did not also show a message when it re-created the links, which would be less confusing.  I suspect this is a quirk of the `-u` option.

Comment: As you still have your question I suggest to use your answer to edit the question and remove the answer.

Comment: @Philippos  Ugh.  I see what you're saying.  I'm kind of not interested in the ultimate question though.  Or, I'm not interested enough to keep going and try and answer it, and I don't expect anyone else would be interested enough to do so.  Are you volunteering to have a spelunk in the code if I edit the question?

Comment: @phk, note that the author of this Answer is the OP; it's an update to their Q, not an Answer -- and not a new question.

Comment: This seems like it answers the original question ("Why did it say it's removing files?")